# Can I POP a value from the stack, but put it nowhere in NASM Assembly?

Tags: x86, stack, nasm, stack-memory, stack-pointer

NASM Assembly, Ubuntu, 32-bit program.

Normally, when popping a value from the stack, I'll do

```
POP somewhere
```

Into a register or a variable. But sometimes, I simply don't want to put it anywhere - I just want to get rid of the next element in the stack. Doing

```
POP
```

Just like that won't work.

A workaround I had was to make a 4-byte variable I don't use at all and dump the `POP` into it. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [x86 assembly: Pop a value without storing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705427/x86-assembly-pop-a-value-without-storing-it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adjust the stack pointer by four bytes (or some other amount), ignoring whatever value was on top:

```
add esp, 4
```

Comment: And that literally deletes the next element in the stack? If I `push` a 5, and did what you told me, the next time I do a `pop`, I won't get the 5 I had, right?

Comment: Try it.  :)  You'll see the same code used in some NASM example functions.

Comment: @Omega: Popping doesn't delete anything, it just moves the stack pointer.

Answer (score 5):

As John Zwinck already pointed out, you can use `add esp, 4` to effectively "pop into nowhere". And of course, you can use other constants to pop only a word (2), two dwords (8), or whatever.

If you want to not modify the arithmetic status flags, you may use `lea esp, [esp + 4]` instead. (This does not work for a 16-bit stack addressed by `sp` because `[sp + immediate]` cannot be encoded.)

If you have a stack frame created with `ebp` pointing at the base, you may get away with just `mov esp, ebp` to discard all the stack slots allocated since `ebp` was set. (Part of the operation of the `leave` instruction is effectively the same as `mov esp, ebp`.)

Likewise, you may change the stack pointer by using `lea esp, [ebp - immediate]` but that requires keeping track of how far `ebp` is from your desired `esp` value.

Finally, aside from popping into a scratch memory destination, you can always pop into registers that are not "in use", ie may be clobbered by your code at that point. For example, here I use `pop cx` twice just to get rid of the stack slots, which is shorter to encode than `add sp, 4`: https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldosboot/file/b7cf0f0fee06/boot.asm#l1186