# NASM should I pop function argument after calling a function?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, callstack, calling-convention

Let's say I have a nasm function like this:

```
inc:
    mov rax,[rsp + 8]
    add [rax],BYTE 1
    ret
```

And I am calling this function like this:

```
push some_var
call inc
```

I want to pass an argument to the function through the stack, so I push `some_var` and then call my function. In the function my item is second on the stack so I take it like: `mov rax,[rsp+8]`

My question is: after calling function should I somehow pop my argument from the stack? If so, can I somehow delete it from the stack, I mean pop it, but not to register? (Because I don't need this argument anymore.)

UPDATE: I found that I can simply `add rsp,8` and that's how I can remove item from stack. But is that good practice? To remove the argument from the stack after calling function?

Comment: You can both pop the argument off the stack or increment the stack pointer to remove it.  Both are fine and used by compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice is to pass args in registers like the standard x86-64 calling conventions that compilers use.  e.g. x86-64 System V passes the first 6 integer/pointer args in registers, so your function would be
`add byte [rdi], 1` / `ret`, and not need any cleanup.
The caller would only need `mov edi, some_var` or `lea rdi, [rel some_var]`.

(Basics of user-space function calling documented in [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-i386-and-x86-6) even though the title mentions system calls.  Full details in https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI.  It's also handy to actually look at what compilers do for simple C functions: see [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output))

If you *do* need to pass a stack arg, popping it into a dummy register like `pop rcx` can actually be *more* efficient than `add rsp, 8`, for similar reasons to why compilers sometimes use a dummy `push` to reserve one qword stack slot / re-align the stack by 16: [Why does this function push RAX to the stack as the first operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773787/why-does-this-function-push-rax-to-the-stack-as-the-first-operation)  But if you have more than 1 stack arg for the caller to clean up, use
`add rsp, 8 * n` where `n` is the number of stack slots.

It's also possible to have the callee clean the stack by using `ret 8`.  But that defeats the chance for you to have the caller leave the stack space allocated and do `mov` stores into it, e.g. in preparation for another `call`.

Comment: Link for context on the calling convention you mentioned: [Where is the x86-64 System V ABI documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133812/where-is-the-x86-64-system-v-abi-documented/40348010#40348010)

Answer (score 4):

I listed some ways to remove things from the stack in this answer: [Can I POP a value from the stack, but put it nowhere in NASM Assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418781/can-i-pop-a-value-from-the-stack-but-put-it-nowhere-in-nasm-assembly/57663744#57663744), to summarise:

- `add rsp, x`
- `lea rsp, [rsp + x]`
- `mov rsp, rbp` (also part of `leave`)
- `lea rsp, [rbp - x]`
- popping into otherwise unused registers

Other than that, whether you *should* remove parameters from the stack in the caller is determined by whether your calling convention mandates [caller clean-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Caller_clean-up) or the opposite, callee cleanup. Callee cleanup is done by specifying the number of bytes to remove from the stack as [an immediate operand](https://ulukai.org/ecm/insref.htm#insRET) to the `retn` instruction. For example:

```
    ...
    ; caller code
    push rax
    push rdi
    call testfunction
    ...


    ; function code
testfunction:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rcx, qword [rbp + 16]
    ...
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    retn 16
```