# "Segmentation fault" when trying to print an integer

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

I've been trying to write an assembly procedure that prints a number.
I wrote the procedure `printc` that prints a single character:

```
printc: push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp

        mov     eax, 4
        mov     ebx, 1

        add     [ebp + 8], byte '0' 
        lea     ecx, [ebp + 8]

        mov     edx, 1

        int     0x80

        mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp

        ret
```

Then I tried to write `printi` so:

```
printi: push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp

        mov     eax, [ebp + 8]

        cmp     eax, 0
        je      end

        mov     ebx, 10
        div     ebx

        push    eax
        call    printi

        push    edx
        call    printc

end:    mov     esp, ebp
        pop     ebp

        ret
```

Finally, I called `printi`:

```
_start: push    32 
        call    printi
```

And got `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.
Any idea why?

Comment: Please run your program in a debugger (Google how to use `gdb`) and check at which line it crashes and what values the registers had at that point. This should greatly help.

Comment: Did you just let execution fall off the end of `_start` after `printi` returns?  If it returns...   This is why we have debuggers, stop wasting your time just looking at the segfault and find out how exactly the CPU runs your code.  Also use `strace ./a.out` to see if you made any system calls successfully.  BTW, see also [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) for a non-recursive loop that does this more efficiently.

Comment: Another problem: You use `push` to put parameters for `printc` onto the stack but you don't `pop` or otherwise discard these stack slots anywhere. See [NASM should I pop function argument after calling a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830765/nasm-should-i-pop-function-argument-after-calling-a-function/60831084#60831084)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Peter Cordes correctly said, your program would fall off `_start` and return to undefined code, if it didn't crash earlier due to infinite recursion in `printi`.

The reason there is infinite recursion: you probably think that `div ebx` divides `EAX` by 10. It doesn't: it divides `EDX:EAX` 64-bit value by `EBX`, and you don't control `EDX`.

Zeroing out `EDX` before `DIV` allows the program to print something (but not the desired output), then crash when it falls off `printi`.

Comment: Also see my comment on the question.