# system V (x86_64 ) abi calling conventions: should caller-saved variables be saved in recursive calls (even if they are not changed)?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, att, abi

Say I want to implement a function for summing the numbers in a given range:

```c
int sumRange(int start, int end);
```

And this is the implementation I came up with: (AT&T asm syntax)

```x86asm
sumRange:
   cmp %edi, %esi
   jl return_zero #jump if start > end
   
   #Pre-Call:
   push %edi
   inc %edi
   # push %esi
   call sumRange
   
   #Post-Call:
   # pop %esi   
   pop %edi

   add %edi, %eax
   ret # return start + sumRange(start+1, end)

return_zero:
   xor %eax, %eax
   ret # return 0
```

Note that both *%edi* and *%esi* are caller-saved register.
*%edi* changes between the frames of the different recursive levels of *sumRange* so it must be saved in the Pre-Call, but *%esi* is not changed in the recursive call - so the code will still work without saving that register.

The question is: does this code meet the System V convention?

I think that it does not:
The convention does not consider what registers the called function actually changes (as far as I have found).
Therefore we are required to assume all caller-saved registers might change after a function-call.

Also, even if we do not make use of *%esi* after the recursive call, I would expect *%esi* to have it's proper value for the **entire** scope of *sumRange.*

Comment: It's a recursive call to the same function so you know the implementation. Yo do not need to assume anythinig. Your function adheres to the ABI from the viewpoint of the top level external caller. For the recursive call, it does not matter (but may make maintaining the code more difficult if you later happen to change the implementation).

Comment: You *don't* need to save `end`, but not because it's not modified. You don't need to save it, because you pass it unmodified to the function you call, and **you don't use it beyond the recursive call**. Whether the called function modifies it or not doesn't matter, that variable is dead already.

Comment: @EOF I understand that it does not matter whether or not I save %esi in terms of code correctness, but I want to emphasize I'm exclusively asking about the convention. Would this mean that the convention treats recursive calls differently than regular function calls?

Comment: @yosef The convention is that you need to save caller-saved variables **that are still live after the call**. No more, no less. Whether the call is recursive or not does not matter for this.

Comment: From the point of view of compliance with the calling convention, all that matters is you preserve all the registers that are callee-saved (rbx, rbp, r12-r15).  And you do - you never modify any of them at all.  That is no different between recursive and non-recursive.  How you manage the caller-saved registers is important for your function's correctness, but not for ABI compliance.

Comment: Maybe the term "caller-saved" is confusing you?  It does not mean that you absolutely *have* to save that register when making a function call - you only have to save it *if* you have a use for its value after the call returns.  Some people prefer the term "call-clobbered" which simply states what happens to the register around a call - its value may be overwritten - rather than appearing to tell you what you should do about it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62719139/7509065