# Can't pass parameters to function in assembly x86

Tags: function, assembly, parameters, x86, nasm

I'm trying to pass a string and it's length to the registers `ecx` and `edx` through the stack, but i'm getting a segmentation fault:

```
global main

section .data
        var db "this is the message",0
        varlen equ $- var

section .text

print:
        mov  eax, 4
        mov  ebx, 1
        mov  ecx, [ebp + 4]
        mov  edx, [ebp + 8]
        int 0x80

        ret

main:
        push varlen
        push var
        call print

        mov  eax, 1
        mov  ebx, 0
        int 0x80
```

Comment: You wanted `esp` not `ebp`.

Comment: And it looks like that you forgot to pop 2 times (or to increment esp), after calling print function. Before calling a function you pushed 2 values to the stack. And after returning from function they are still there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830765/nasm-should-i-pop-function-argument-after-calling-a-function/60831084#60831084

Comment: @Eliahu since the next thing the program does is terminate it does not matter. But in general, yeah, you want to balance the stack.

Comment: @Eliahu how am i supposed to do that? do you have an example? I've seen the post but still ditn't get it.

Comment: @spyblock right after the line "call print" put: add esp, 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want, your function to have prologue and epilogue, do the following:

```
print:
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp
    mov  eax, 4
    mov  ebx, 1
    mov  ecx, [ebp + 8]
    mov  edx, [ebp + 12]
    int  0x80
    mov  esp, ebp
    pop  ebp
    ret
```

otherwise:

```
print:
    mov  eax, 4
    mov  ebx, 1
    mov  ecx, [esp + 4]
    mov  edx, [esp + 8]
    int  0x80
    ret
```

and in your `main`:

```
main:
    push varlen
    push var
    call print
    add  esp, 8
    mov  eax, 1
    xor  ebx, ebx
    int 0x80
```

Comment: why do i have to add 8 to esp?

Comment: @spyblock Because before your call instruction, you have pushed 8 bytes and later on you have to bring your stack pointer back, otherwise you are losing the memory and it can be worse if you call ```main``` from another function. In later, you changed your ```esp``` and cannot go back to original ```esp``` when ever you finish your function.

Comment: @spyblock  `push varlen` **sub**tracted 4 from ESP and wrote *varlen* in stack memory, and afterwards `push var` also **sub**tracted 4 from ESP and wrote *var* in stack memory. Upon returning from *print* those 8 bytes are still on the stack. You balance this situation by **add**ing 8 to ESP.

Comment: With or without a function prologue/epilogue, it would be best to preserve the EBX register (on the stack) since it is a call-preserved register.

Comment: @spyblock: You don't in this case, the exit system-call doesn't care where ESP points.  If you were going to `ret` from `main` instead, then you would need to remove the args you pushed to get ESP pointing at your return address again.